# STL file reader issues

Tags: javascript, three.js, step, stl-format

I am using STLLoader.js to draw components. Every components are rendered properly with one defined color but that is not look like a real world component.

[image]

Above image is my three.js implementation using STLLoader.js (Binary STL file used) as I have read this format supports color for the components.

Below image is rendered one of my windows software and there I have used Step file. I want to render component same as look like in below image so its look like a real world component.

[image]

Is there any way to get correct colored output in three.js? I have searched a lot but didn't get a way to implement it. Please help me to go in forward direction.

```
        var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {               
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x75D3DC, ambient: 0x75D3DC, specular: 0x75D3DC, shininess: 200/*, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors */} );

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.x = x - boardMaxX + w/2 ;
            mesh.position.y = - 5 ;
            mesh.position.z = z - boardMaxY + h/2 ;

            mesh.rotation.set( (rotation * Math.PI / 180.0), 0, 0 );

            mesh.scale.set(2, 2, 2);

            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            board.add(mesh);
            objects.push( mesh );

            i = i + 5;
            componenetDraw(componentArray[i] * scaleX, -7, componentArray[i + 1] * scaleY, componentArray[i + 2], componentArray[i + 4]);
        } );

    loader.load( fileName );
    }
```

The above code is used for read STL file. But I dont have code for read STEP file.

Comment: The STL format does not support colors. It has nothing to do with the loader.

Comment: @gaitat Is there any other way to do the same thing using different file format?

Comment: @Shiladittya I am not sure I understand the question. Is [this](http://ar3f.in/goochShading.html) the shading you want to achieve?

Comment: could you post your code and STEP file? That would help

Comment: @Shiladittya If you are responding to a particular user, you must use the "@username" format, otherwise the user will not be notified of your comment.

Comment: @rochb I added the code for stl file reader but I dont have the code for STEP file.

Comment: @WestLangley We can see the exact color using STEP file in windows software but when I read the stl file then I am not getting the exact color. I want to same color which is look like real component.

Comment: Read the comments in [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_assimp2json.html). Maybe you can convert from STEP to a format that will contain the colors. See http://assimp.sourceforge.net.

Comment: @WestLangley I have already tried to another format like vrml, wrl, obj file. But its also has the same problem. First of all vrml (version 2) its not working in three.js its showing color format is not supported for that reason I develop one prototype program in java which read vrml file but its also not showing proper color. Is there any other way to read STEP file and use this geometry in three.js. For example if I used any c++ stand alone tool to read and its return the 3D object. Thanx for your reply.

Comment: `JSONLoader` supports face colors and vertex colors. Perhaps you can write a converter. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for your reply. I have tried with other formats. First of all I just convert STEP to PLY and then JSON and within json file manually changed the color and its working partially. Is there any available tool which convert directly STEP to JSON file?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

STEP files usually contain BREP geometry, and you need a CAD kernel to convert BREP to mesh.  Take a look at BRL-CAD, FreeCAD, pythonOCC, and OCE/OCCT for CAD kernels, and meshlab for converting meshes.

Comment: I have already used FreeCad software for covert STEP to mesh(STL, OBJ, PLY etc). After conversion form STEP to another format, convert file does support the color. Its supports only one color that is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a file format that allows to specify color per triangle-set, not only per mesh. To my knowledge this works with vrml, which can be exported by FreeCAD.

Annother idea would be to split your part into multiple ones and export every color region as single mesh with on color.